# Intent definition for different class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an Util class in which I have the openFile() method for opening files. I call this method from another class (Browser.class) and I try to launch specific intent to third class called ImageViewer.class. My question is that how should I define the intent in the Util class that it can be launched by any other class? Here is my definition that I came over so far.

```
public static void openFile(final Context context, final File target) {
    final String mime = MimeTypes.getMimeType(target);
    final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    final boolean defaultOpen = true;
    if (defaultOpen) {
        if(mime.startsWith("image/")){
            Intent i1 = new Intent(String.valueOf(ImageViewer.class));
            i1.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(target), mime);
            context.startActivity(i1);
        }
    }
```

This is my logcat :

```
Process: com.tproductions.Openit, PID: 5796
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=class com.tproductions.Openit.ImageViewer dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0001.JPG typ=image/jpeg }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
        at com.tproductions.Openit.utils.SimpleUtils.openFile(SimpleUtils.java:318)
        at com.tproductions.Openit.Browser.listItemAction(Browser.java:446)
        at com.tproductions.Openit.Browser.access$300(Browser.java:46)
        at com.tproductions.Openit.Browser$1.onItemClick(Browser.java:208)
```

Comment: I wanted to know what to put in the `Intent i1 = `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an intent from non `Activity` class, use `context` as constructor parameter

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ImageViewer.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a non-activity class, i'll suggest you do something like this:

```
 private Context mContext;

 public utilClassName(Context context) { //pass in the context from the 
                                         //Activity class you'll be using the object
    mContext = context;
 }
```

and then:

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(context, ImageViewer.class).
                        setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The earlier one worked too